# Pdf Packing Slip - add subtotal for simple product

Tags: magento-1.8, pdf, simple-product, shipment, totals

I need to display the prices of the purchased products on the packing slip. I managed to display it for bundle products, but for the simple products it's always showing $0,00.

I was trying to do the same as in the onvoice pdf, cause there it works. So I was using the same call as in `\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\Default.php` where it says :

```
    // draw item Prices
    $i = 0;
    $prices = $this->getItemPricesForDisplay();
    foreach ($prices as $priceData){           

        /* draw Subtotal */
        $lines[$i][] = array(
            'text'  => $priceData['subtotal'],
            'feed'  => 520,                
            'align' => 'right'
        );
        $i++;
    }
```

The `getItemPricesForDisplay()`function is defined within `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Abstract.php`. So I used the same code for getting the prices in the `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Shipment\Default.php` but it's always returning 0,00.

Why is that? Do I have to change something or do it completely different to get the price of that product in the packing slip?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
$this->insertTotals($page, $order);
```

directly after

```
/* Draw item */
            $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
            $page = end($pdf->pages);
        }
```